# mongoose array query construction with javascript template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb and mongoose with expressjs

My db has the following array:

```
_id:6262013fa90e7b533809140d
isactive:true
schedule:Array
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
name:"whatever"
description:"describe somthing"
```

In my expressjs route I'm trying to build a query like this:

```
app.get("/getmenu",  (req, res)=>{
    let getdate = new Date()
    let getday = getdate.getDay()-1
    
     Category.find({ "schedule.1.availabletoday" : "true" }, 
        function(error, categories){   
          console.log("categories :", categories)
          res.json({"activecategories" : categories})      
 })
    
})
```

This does work and returned the correct results except that I need the line below to inlcude a template literal or something equivalent, let me explain:

```
"schedule.1.availabletoday"
```

I need to replace the 1 with getday value. If getday value is 0, then the query will be

```
"schedule.0.availabletoday"
```

If getday value is 2, then the query will go looking for :

```
"schedule.2.availabletoday"
```

So how do I include the getday value in my query to be like this:

```
"schedule.getday.availabletoday"
```

I tried

```
"schedule.${getday}.availabletoday"
```

but it returned empty results, by empty I mean this :  []

I tried

```
"schedule.getday.availabletoday"
```

the query returned empty results : []

According to the mongodb doc, to search the array elements, I need the quotation mark around my array element query. So I can't just write this:

```
 schedule.getday.availabletoday
```

Do I need to update my node or expressjs application to be able to use template literals or is it something else I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Template String as

```
`schedule.${getday}.availabletoday`
```

As per your example:

```
app.get("/getmenu",  (req, res)=>{
    let getdate = new Date()
    let getday = getdate.getDay()-1
    
     Category.find({ `schedule.${getday}.availabletoday` : true }, 
        function(error, categories){   
          console.log("categories :", categories)
          res.json({"activecategories" : categories})      
 })
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak but unfortunately I get an empty [] back from the query when I include the ${getday} template literal in the query. If I replace it with 1, it returns the correct results.

Comment: Please check if "true" in `schedule.${getday}.availabletoday : true` is Boolean or String?

if Boolean use true else use true as string. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I was just happy you pointed me for the reason as it drove me crazy. It is working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
let getdate = new Date();
let day = getdate.getDay()-1;
let query = {};
query[`schedule.${day}.availabletoday`] = true;

Category.find(query, (err, categories)=> {
  console.log("categories :", categories)
  res.json({"activecategories" : categories}) 
})
```

Comment: With this way you will be able to add more condition to your query.

Comment: Luis, I like your code and I'll use the query object way to construct my query from now on. Unfortunately ${day} returning an empty array. when I replace the ${day} with the digit 1, I get the right results. It looks like ${} - template literal - can't be placed in query or maybe I need to update my experssjs or node. I'm still searching online.

Comment: query[`schedule.${1}.availabletoday`] = true; works fine?

Comment: "schedule.1.availabletoday" = true works fine and not "schedule.${1}.availabletoday"